# I want to make an action from one View Controller to another in swift 3 xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, swift3, viewcontroller

I have a ImageView in the first view controller and in the other view controller a Action Button- The role of the button is to change the Image in The first View Controller by this code.!

ImageThemed is the first ImageView.

This action is in the second view controller.

```
@IBAction func MM(_ sender: Any) {
     ImageThemed.image = UIImage(named:"Nike.png")
```

All I want to do is to set an image in the first view controller by pressing the button in the second view controller. As the 2nd view controller is embedded in the first view controller.

How can I do this ?

Comment: Nothing yet.! As i have no idea, how to do it..!

Comment: Have you searched about it ? there are a lots of solution given you just need to google it .

Comment: do you suggest anything??

Comment: Read about protocols

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best solution would be using **Delegation**.
You have to declare a **protocol** in the second view controller (the one with the button):

```
protocol SomeOtherViewControllerDelegate {    
    func changeImageButtonPressed()
}
...

class SomeOtherViewController:UIViewController {
... // your existing properties
var delegate: SomeOtherViewControllerDelegate!
... // properties, methods etc...
}
```

Also you have to conform the `FirstViewController` (the one with `UIImageView`) to your protocol `SomeOtherViewControllerDelegate`:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, SomeOtherViewControllerDelegate {
...
    func changeImageButtonPressed() {
        ImageThemed.image = UIImage(named:"Nike.png") // change the image
    }
}
```

Then wherever you're embedding the `SomeOtherViewController` into your `FirstViewController`, you have to set the delegate:

```
let someVC:SomeOtherViewController = ...
// self = your FirstViewController instance
someVC.delegate = self
```